# Setting the Location of Groups

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

A newbie question. As I've explained in a prior post, I'm coming to SVG Land from Flash loaded with ActionScript expectations and misconceptions.

I've built an interactive graphic using D3 and I'm nearly finished except that I want to add a little pop-up box that displays when a user mouses over a state. Right now it appears as a static object labeled "West Virginia" on the left side of the stage:

http://www.50laboratories.com/miscellany/demographicclout2.html

The pop-up is a group with its own distinct ID. I need to be able to set its x and y location depending on the state being hovered over, but so far can't figure out how. It seems to me that I should be able to address a group in my JavaScript as I would a named movie clip in Flash, but visiting API references like this one, https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference, I see no references to methods and properties of group objects. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want some tooltips.  Well there's been quite a bit of discussion on that topic in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/-1oLMKUez3M/g3UjfyvKQIsJ) google groups discussion for instance (which has plenty of links to examples in it).

Comment: Looks promising. Funny, I never thought of them as tooltips but, yes, that's essentially what they are. I'll investigate the links over the next couple of days. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike actionscript, svg elements are dom nodes and manipulating them involves either setting their attributes or style properties. You could manipulate these by calling certain attribute/style setters of the dom nodes, but since you're using d3, you set those attributes/styles using d3's setters.

The way to position a  element with d3 is to
1. select it, by the id you assigned it
2. set its `transform` attribute to `translate([some-x], [some-y])`

```
d3.select("#statepopup").attr("transform", "translate(50,100)");
```

P.S.
The transform attribute is also how you can scale and rotate the group.

Comment: Thanks. I've had some previous experience with the transform attribute. Before I partially D3-ified the SVG, I tried to set the height and position of the bars in the barchart via the transform attribute. I was utterly unable to get the simultaneous scaling and positioning of the bars right, even after posting the question here. So I gave up on the straight-SVG approach after I learned that with D3 I could just set the height, x and y attibutes as I was used to doing in ActionScript. Since in this case I'm just positioning and not scaling, I shouldn't have any trouble.